# Insert script tag in textarea with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I'm trying to create a textarea with an embed code, so a user can copy that code.
I have two methods of embedding (first method is script with paired div), the other one is iframe).
I enable the user to select a size of the embedded widget through parameters sent to the server.

The textarea content should be this `<script src="http://mysite.com/embed/product_id/width/height"></script>`

Usually, that would be set as an encoded HTML (& lt; & gt;) when printed out through the HTML, but in this case I need to set it through Javascript.

**So this doesn't work:**

```
$('textarea.embed_code').val('<script src="http://mysite.com/embed/product_id/width/height"></script>');
```

The closing tag breaks the initial script tag where this line is set.

Any suggestion about how to change the width and height in the script source would be fine too (regex, string replace ...), in which case I'll just print out the textarea content from the HTML.

Any other tag works fine, the issue is just with `<script>`

Comment: Don't use elements designed for user input to display output to users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To include the string `"</script>"` as data in a `<script>` element, escape the `/`: `"<\/script>"`. This will break the HTML end tag syntax while being equivalent in JavaScript string literal syntax.

Comment: I was confused by what you meant by escape the / :, but basically you meant escaping the *ending* script tag i.e. <\/script>. Works great!

Comment: @Qasim — I meant "Escape the forward slash character". There is only one forward slash character. It happens to be the second character in the end tag.